# How to utilize the C++ Parquet library logical classes

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a need to invoke a method within a derived class.  This is straightforward enough in the abstract.  However I am utilizing the Parquet C++ library.  There are a series of classes surrounding the Parquet logical types.  Their base class is simply `LogicalType` with the derived classes inheriting publicly from that base class.  Because their `LogicalType` is rather long, I will include the relevant portions of it here:

```
class PARQUET_EXPORT LogicalType {
 public:
  struct Type {
    enum type {
      UNDEFINED = 0,  // Not a real logical type
      STRING = 1,
      MAP,
      LIST,
      ENUM,
      DECIMAL,
      DATE,
      TIME,
      TIMESTAMP,
      INTERVAL,
      INT,
      NIL,  // Thrift NullType: annotates data that is always null
      JSON,
      BSON,
      UUID,
      NONE  // Not a real logical type; should always be last element
    };
  };

  struct TimeUnit {
    enum unit { UNKNOWN = 0, MILLIS = 1, MICROS, NANOS };
  };
  LogicalType(const LogicalType&) = delete;
  LogicalType& operator=(const LogicalType&) = delete;
  virtual ~LogicalType() noexcept;

[snipped for brevity reasons]

 protected:
  LogicalType();

  class Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<const Impl> impl_;
};
```

The class I am interested in is the `TimestampLogicalType` class, which is defined as follows:

```
class PARQUET_EXPORT TimestampLogicalType : public LogicalType {
 public:
  static std::shared_ptr<const LogicalType> Make(bool is_adjusted_to_utc,
                                                 LogicalType::TimeUnit::unit time_unit,
                                                 bool is_from_converted_type = false,
                                                 bool force_set_converted_type = false);
  bool is_adjusted_to_utc() const;
  LogicalType::TimeUnit::unit time_unit() const;

  /// \brief If true, will not set LogicalType in Thrift metadata
  bool is_from_converted_type() const;

  /// \brief If true, will set ConvertedType for micros and millis
  /// resolution in legacy ConvertedType Thrift metadata
  bool force_set_converted_type() const;

 private:
  TimestampLogicalType() = default;
};
```

I'd like to utilize the `time_unit()` method in particular.  However, the manner in which you discover a column's metadata (ergo the column descriptor's logical type method) will return you a `LogicalType` object, regardless of what logical type the column actually is.  To be precise, it returns to you a shared pointer to a const `LogicalType` object.  However the `LogicalType` class does not have the method I need (naturally), so you need the `TimestampLogicalType` object in order to invoke `time_unit()`.  Because `LogicalType` has a virtual destructor, I was thinking that I could use `dynamic_cast<>` to convert the `LogicalType` object to a `TimestampLogicalType` object.  However that doesn't work.

So I dunno.  When I think about the problem, I get the feeling that the answer is obvious, rudimentary/fundamental, and something that I should be able to see straight away.  However after three or four days of playing around with it, I am still not seeing how to make this work.  Any feedback?  Am I just thinking about this in the wrong way?

I am using the Arrow/Parquet libraries, version 4.0.1.  Building on a LAX box, x86_64, GCC/G++ 7.4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured this out; I am not certain where I went wrong initially, but I revisited the `dynamic_cast<>` approach this morning.  For simplification reasons, I broke out each step into its own, separate instruction.  This is what I came up with:

```
parquet::LogicalType *localTimestampBase = const_cast<parquet::LogicalType*>(localLogical.get());

parquet::TimestampLogicalType *localTimestamp = dynamic_cast<parquet::TimestampLogicalType*>( localTimestampBase );

std::cout << "   Logical Type TIMESTAMP is-timestamp = " << std::boolalpha << localLogical->is_timestamp() << "\n";
std::cout << "   Logical Type TIMESTAMP is-adjusted-to-utc = " << std::boolalpha << localTimestamp->is_adjusted_to_utc() << "\n";
std::cout << "   Logical Type TIMESTAMP time unit = " << time_unit_string( localTimestamp->time_unit() ) << "\n";
```

And this works, thus:

```
   Logical Type TIMESTAMP is-timestamp = true
   Logical Type TIMESTAMP is-adjusted-to-utc = true
   Logical Type TIMESTAMP time unit = nanoseconds
```

Hope this helps someone.  Thanks!

Comment: The above could be simplified to just this: ```const parquet::TimestampLogicalType *localTimestamp = dynamic_cast<const parquet::TimestampLogicalType*>( columnDescriptor->logical_type().get() );```